# iOS: SWRevealViewController not showing navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm trying to implement slide menu using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) . Here is my story board:
[image]

Here is how I'm loading the view controller from the main viewController:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    UIStoryboard *stryBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    [stryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
    NewViewController *vc = [stryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any of you knows why the navigation bar is not showing on my device?, or what I'm doing wrong for the navigation bar not to show?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your navigation bar is missing because you present your "NewViewController" modally by using:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion;
```

You have three choices to fix this issue based on your requirement:

1. Push your "NewViewController" to your initial ViewController which is a UINavigationController by using:

   ```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
   ```
2. Present your NavigationController (the one your "NewViewController" is rootViewController) modally;
3. **(Which I guess is what you want)** Present your SWRevealViewController modally;